# In CUDA PTX, what does %warpid mean, really?

Tags: cuda, ptx

IN CUDA PTX, there's a special register which holds a thread's warp's index: `%warpid`. Now, the spec says:

> Note that `%warpid`  is volatile and returns the location of a thread
> at the moment when read, but its value may change during execution,
> e.g., due to rescheduling of threads following preemption.

Umm, what location is that? Shouldn't it be the location within the block, e.g. for a 1-dimensional grid `%tid.x / warpSize`? Is it some slot-for-a-warp within the SM (e.g. warp scheduler or some internal queue)? I'm confused.

<sub>Motivation: I wanted to spare myself the trouble of calculating `%tid.x / warpSize` as well as free up a register, by using this special register. However, in retrospect this is a false motivation, because reading a special register is expensive; see: [What's the most efficient way to calculate the warp id / lane id in a 1-D grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44337309/1593077)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the next 25 words of the documentation which directly follow after the quotation which you posted in your question:

> For this reason, %ctaid and %tid should be used to compute a virtual
>   warp index if such a value is needed in kernel code;

and then

> %warpid is intended mainly to enable profiling and diagnostic code to
>   sample and log information such as work place mapping and load
>   distribution.

So no, you can't use it for what you want. **`%warpid` is effectively a scheduler slot ID** rather than a constant, unique warp index within a block.

Comment: Emboldend the actual answer. And - I did read that part, it just didn't seem like that could really be the case. With that being the case I really don't see why they called it %warpid rather than `%warpsmslot` or `%warpidinsm` or `%warpslot` etc.